# Android webview automatically detect files in webpage?

Tags: java, android, html

```
public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String extension; //Check uri format to avoid null 
    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        //If scheme is a content 
        final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));

    } else {
        //If scheme is a File 
        //This will replace white spaces with %20 and also other special characters. This will avoid returning null values on file name with spaces and special characters. 
        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());

    }
    return extension;

}
```

I tried this not working

Comment: you can't detect files in the web page, as there are no files in web page, only text. Explain what you want to do.

Comment: Someone help me

Comment: Once you explain what you want - we will try

Comment: Thankyou I appreciate your response
I just want to get the files like (jpg,mp3 etc)" Mimetype"
 like Internet_download_Manager ( it's automatically detect if there any videos or mp3 in a current webpage)

Comment: For better understanding please give an example of HTML, and what you want to retrieve from it. I think I can help, but better to make sure I understand what you want.

Comment: @VladMatvienko 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kXFhLColmcNGxfWmFIT01aOUk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @VladMatvienko 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kXFhLColmcNGxfWmFIT01aOUk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kXFhLColmcNGxfWmFIT01aOUk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @VladMatvienko https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kXFhLColmcNGxfWmFIT01aOUk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3kXFhLColmcNGxfWmFIT01aOUk/view?usp=drivesdk